# Android , POST запрос , проблема с IOException

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, try-catch

Писал изначально код в java, перенес в android без изменений. Потребовал для запуска метода, засунуть его в проверку исключений try,catch и теперь каждый раз выходит catch. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

```
   try {
        sendPOST();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "catch");
    }

}

public static void sendPOST() throws IOException {
    URL obj = new URL(POST_URL);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    // For POST only - START

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

    os.write(POST_PARAMS.getBytes());
    System.out.println(POST_PARAMS);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    // For POST only - END

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("POST Response Code :: " + responseCode);

    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { //success
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                con.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        // print result
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("POST request not worked");
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Если хотите решения проблемы, то приложите стектрейс. 2. Начните использовать Retrofit для работы с такими задачами.

Comment: Не хотелось бы переписывать полностью код.

Comment: Зато эти ваши 20-30 строк сократятся штук до 5 и это будет работать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема была в потоках , [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494510/post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-networkonmainthreadexception) есть решение (очень простой способ).

Answer (score 0):

У вас либо отсутствует разрешение на интернет в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

либо выскакивает ошибка [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html), возникающая при попытке обращения в сеть на `API>=14`.

Либо оба варианта разом.

**Решение:**
Проверьте манифест, перенесите работу с сетью в отдельный поток. С помощью `AsyncTask` или одной из многочисленных библиотек для работы с сетью.