# Post запрос, NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, http, httpclient

Нужно отправить POST Запрос с логином и паролем и получить токен. В моем коде вроде все верно, но приложение вылетает сразу же с ошибкой.

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hondle.biling/com.example.hondle.biling.activity.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Код:

```
   Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {


        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        // replace with your url
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://tarampampam.ru/login");


        //Post Data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "padavan"));
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "123123123"));


        //Encoding POST data
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // log exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //making POST request.

        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // write response to log


    }
};
```

UPD: Спасибо за помощь, извините за популярный вопрос. AsyncTask , для меня, как для начинающего разработчика, сложен, поэтому я использовал стандартную библиотеку THREAD, используя [данную](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/thread.php) статью. Код исправил, что бы другим было на что опираться.

Comment: Как насчет поискать, прежде, чем задавать вопрос? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=NetworkOnMainThreadException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NetworkOnMainThreadException` возникает на устройствах с `API>14` когда вы пытаетесь ходить в Интернеты из основного (`UI`) потока.

Решается это выносом запроса к сети в отдельный [поток](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6343299/3212712). Например, используя `AsyncTask`